# How to use LSTM, TFT, or other RNN with time series of different lengths

Tags: neural-networks, forecasting, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, temporal-fusion-transformer

I have a dataset of financial transactions per day with the volume of the transaction and the price of the transaction. For each day I want to calculate the volume weighted average price at the end of the day. However, the number of transactions and the times of the transactions vary for each day.

What is the standard approach to train a LSTM, TFT, or other NN to solve this problem?

- Padding
- Sampling (but for my problem this will not work)

The dataset looks like this:

Day | Time | Transaction # | Price | Volume

For each day I want to predict the volume weighted average price before the day ends, so my target is

Day | Volume weighted average price

Comment: Pad the sequences and then ignore predictions for padded time steps.